# Sed - find and replace text in html code (from one language to another)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace

I have html file index.html with english version.
I want to create one more language version. I think the best way to do this is use sed. So I want to automatically change language version to another and save it in new file using sed.

For example my index:

```
    <section class="p-b-10">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="heading-text heading-section">
    <h2>THE COMPANY</h2>
    <span class="lead">The most happiest eu, sodales vel dolor. </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 m-t-60">
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="100" data-delay="100" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">One Sun   </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="94" data-delay="200" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">Two    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="78" data-delay="300" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">JQUERY    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="65" data-delay="400" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">Three | ok   </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="65" data-delay="400" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">Three    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Sed shoud find and replace all given english words to spanish inside my whole code.

The Company (replace to) Empresa

One Sun (replace to) Uno Sol

Two (replace to) Dos

Three | ok (replace to) Tres | ok

so should looks like below:

```
    <section class="p-b-10">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="heading-text heading-section">
    <h2>Empresa    </h2>
    <span class="lead">The most happiest eu, sodales vel dolor.     
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 m-t-60">
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="100" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">Uno Sol       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="94" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">Dos    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="78" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">JQUERY    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="65" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">Tres | ok       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-progress-bar-container title-up small color">
    <div class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="65" data-type="%">
    <div class="progress-title">Three    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Please help!
Thank You

Comment: Do you have access to xml-aware tools such as xmllint or xmlstarlet? If so tag your question with those to get a robust answer.

Answer (score 1):

*I want to create one more language version.*

This is called [Internationalization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Internationalization) or in short i18n.

*I think the best way to do this is use sed.*

best is subjective, if you are not strictly limited to *sed* and *AWK* I suggest to give a try [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html), as it was made to provide i18n. You would need more time to get started, but in longer run you might more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed like this: `s/FIND/REPLACE/g`
If you want to run multiple sed commands use `;` operator:

```
sed 's/The Company/Empresa/g; s/One Sun/Uno Sol/g; s/Two/Dos/g; s/Three | ok/Tres | ok/g' $YOUR_FILE > spanish.html
```

If you don't want to replace all the words and only the first match, remove the 'g'.

Comment: Think about what that would do if the company name changed to `TwoBrothers` or `One Sunday` instead of `Empresa`. That approach is extremely fragile.

Comment: @what about t argument? what it changing? for example        sed 's/The Company/Empresa/g;t;